How to prevent snowflake from overwriting few columns while creating a view?
I have a view in snowflake, say order, and its create query goes like below:


CREATE or replace view order as(
    select 
    ord.date,
    ord.id,
    ord.amount,
    ord.status,
    ord.static_field1,
    ord.static_field2
    from 
      (select 
      a.date as date, 
      b.id as id, 
      c.amount as amount, 
      d.status as status
      'static_field1' as static_field1,
      'static_field2' as static_field2 
      from a join b join c join d on <join-conditions>
    ) ord);



Since columns - static_field1 and static_field2 need to be updated only one time so I used update command to populate them in the view order.
But the create or replace still needs to be executed for other columns every day. And as soon as we do it again overwrites the static fields.
When above query is executed in FUTURE,  I want the static_field1 and static_field2 to NOT be overwritten with text values 'static_field1' and 'static_field2' as in above query but remain as the values I gave them TODAY while running update command.
Please help on how to achieve this. Is there a way I can use "SELECT (all other fields) EXCLUDE (static fields)" to achieve this or need to change the strategy altogether?

By definition a view is a SQL which is stored as a object in a database, it will display the data the will be returned when the query in the view is executed.  When ever you execute a select from a view it is always going to return the values hard coded for  static_field1 and static_field2 . Could you please let us know what do you mean when you say update the View ? do you mean changing the view defination.

@HimanshuKandpal - After the view is created first time using create view query, afterwards I'll run an UPDATE query on the view to update those static columns with values. example UPDATE Order
SET static_field1 = <some_static_value>
WHERE ID = 3;  Now after that when create view query is executed again after few days, I want snowflake to ignore those static columns and not overwrite them

for view  update , you will have to modify the DDL for the  view.

Does Snowflake really let you update those static_field's?!?
